# Coordinate offsets in xarray and dask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask, python-xarray

I'm making use of xarray as the coordinates and automatic alignment are really useful. and I've been using Dask as the data I'm generally dealing with datasets in the order of terabytes.

I have a 3D source array generated (or loaded) and dependent on wavelength (wl) and x position and y position at origin zero.

I also have a 2D output array dependant only on x and y which accumulates all of the wavelengths from the source array. Idealistically the output would be:

```
output = source.sum('wl')
```

However, the wavelength dependence means that each wavelength offsets the source origin by a certain amount. The best (and ugliest) solution I could come up with is to loop through each wavelength, reassign coordinates, interp up to the output coordinates, stack them into a new array and then sum.
I have an example code that shows what I'm trying to do:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import xarray as xr
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

client = Client(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=2, memory_limit='2GB')

client

# Generate some offset data here
wavelengths = np.linspace(0.1,10,1000)
x_offsets = np.linspace(100,400,1000) 
y_offsets = np.linspace(100,400,1000)

# Coordinate offsets for each wavelength
offset = xr.Dataset(
                    {
                        'x': (['wl'],x_offsets),
                        'y': (['wl'],y_offsets)
                    },
                    coords={
                        'wl': wavelengths
                    })



# Our example source function
source_shape = (1000, 10000, 10000,)

wl_source = np.linspace(0.4,5,source_shape[0])
x_source = np.linspace(-6,6, source_shape[1])
y_source = np.linspace(-6,6, source_shape[2])
source = xr.DataArray(da.random.random(size=source_shape, chunks=(10,400,400)),
                      coords=[wl_source,x_source,y_source],
                      dims=['wl','x','y'])

out_shape = (10000, 10000,)

# Our final output array
x_out = np.linspace(-1000,1000,out_shape[0])
y_out = np.linspace(-1000,1000,out_shape[1])
out = xr.DataArray(da.random.random(size=out_shape, chunks=(4000,4000)),coords=[x_out, y_out], dims=['x','y'])

accum =[]

for wl in source.wl:
    # Build our map from source -> output space
    x_map = offset.interp(wl=wl).x + source.x
    y_map = offset.interp(wl=wl).y + source.y
    
    # Remap coordinates
    source_mapped = source.sel(wl=wl).assign_coords({'x':x_map, 
                            'y':y_map})
    
    # Interp_like unchunks it so need to rechunk it here
    # Interp up to the output coordinates 
    accum.append(
        source_mapped.interp_like(out, method='nearest',kwargs={'fill_value':0}).chunk({'x':4000,'y':4000})
    )

# Accumalate and add to the output
out += xr.concat(accum,dim='wl').sum('wl') 
out
```

This solution ends up with over 1 million tasks, because of that the building of the task graph takes a long time and during computation the gc collection takes a long time, memory is exhausted or I spill so much to disk that I run out of storage. Manually slicing has the same issue.
Additionally, this can't scale if I have more than one source as well. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out a better solution.

I'm wondering if theres a more efficient way of doing this? Either through, dask, xarray or some other library. I'm fairly new to dask and xarray so I'm still trying to get to grips with how they work and how to better chunk and distribute tasks

Sorry for the long winded question!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, and to the happy corner of it that is the xarray/dask world :) I'm having a bit of a hard time following all the field-specific details here and translating them into an xarray implementation question. Any chance you could boil it down to just the issue you're having in terms of coordinates/indexing and tasks? That said, one thing that could be an issue is your chunk size. Dask recommends chunks of a couple hundred MBs. Does increasing your chunks to e.g. `(50*1000*1000)` help? Also, can you decrease the precision, e.g. with `float32` and use even bigger chunks?

Comment: also "Interp_like unchunks it so need to rechunk it here" - this means you're loading your larger-than-memory dataset into memory. just rechunking isn't the answer - this is a non-starter you need to fix. one option is to partition your data along wavelength and do the interpolation within each chunk with [`xr.map_blocks`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.20.1/generated/xarray.DataArray.map_blocks.html).

Comment: oh - sorry that's what you're doing with the for loop. you have lots of different chunk sizes going on here. I'd try to align these to make sure there isn't rechunking going on. Since you're doing interpolation and reindexing along lat/lon, I'd try to only chunk along wavelength and do everything else in memory on each chunk.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado, thanks for the reply! Happy to be in this little corner of chunks and dims! I think you're right with the chunking, I've removed all of the rechunks and started to play around with only the source chunking and I seem to be making progress. :) I think..